# Determine installation scheme/prefix from python package code

Tags: python, package, setuptools, prefix

Say, I have python package with setup.py having following lines:

```
...
packages=['mypkg'],
data_files=[
    ('lib/mypkg/', [...]),
    ('share/mypkg/', [...]),
]
...
```

I assume several executable helpers are to be installed at `$(prefix)/lib/mypkg` and package-related data files are to be installed at `$(prefix)/share/mypkg`. The point is that `$(prefix)` could vary between different distributions. For example, I have `prefix=/usr` by default on centos system and `prefix=/usr/local` by default on debian system. Moreover as I know custom prefix or even custom installation scheme could be supplied as a setup.py parameter.

So, I want to be able to strictly determine where my package data was installed using python code from my package. At the moment I'm using following solution, but it seems clumsy to me and I suppose it will be inefficient in case of custom installation scheme:

```
# mypkg/__init__.py
import os
initpath = __path__[0]

while True:
    datapath, _ = os.path.split(initpath)
    if datapath == initpath:
        break
    initpath, datapath = datapath, os.path.join(datapath, 'share', 'mypkg')
    if os.path.exists(datapath):
        print datapath
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The method I worked up is the following code:

```
import sysconfig
import pkg_resources

self.install_scheme = None
distribution = pkg_resources.get_distribution( 'mypkg' )
lib_path = distribution.location
schemes = sysconfig.get_scheme_names()
for s in schemes:
    p = sysconfig.get_path( 'purelib', s )
    if p == lib_path:
        self.install_scheme = s
```

This works for a package installed via `pip` where package metadata's been created. Change `self.install_scheme` to be a variable you've got access to where you need it (in my case an instance variable on an object everything could access), and use it like this:

```
data_path = sysconfig.get_path( 'data', self.install_scheme )
```

If `self.install_scheme` was `None`, I just went with using `sysconfig.get_path()` without a scheme name (giving me the default scheme for my platform) and hoped for the best.